# How do I save the output of the bat file to a specific location

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I am running this command

```
C:\php\php.exe -f C:\leads\ftp.php
```

with a bat file with a windows scheduled task and all works well. The php file goes to the ftp and grabs a file to store locally. The problem is the location that the file is being stored locally is not in the `C:\leads\` directory. It is being saved in the `C:\Windows\sysWOW64\`

If I click on the bat file it stores the file in the `C:\leads\` directory as expected

any ideas on how to remedy this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add:

```
cd /d C:\leads\
```

before your `php.exe` command.  This is happening because the working directory is set differently whether your batch file is running from a scheduled task or from you double clicking on it.  This way you can force the PHP working directory to be what you want.

Comment: That tells `cd` that you will be changing the current drive as well as the current directory.  In a command prompt type `cd /?` or `help cd` for more information.  Probably not necessary since your files are on the C: drive but it can't hurt.

Comment: i tried cd /d C:\leads\ C:\php\php.exe -f C:\leads\ftp.php and got an error about the path and directory

Comment: @Tamer: That should be on a separate line, before the line containing `php.exe`. Alternatively, you can put it on the same line, but add `&` directly before `php.exe`, like this: `cd /d C:\leads\ & C:\php\php.exe -f C:\leads\ftp.php`